# Using a 9V battery instead of a DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, dc, adapter

I have a DC power adapter that has the following specs:

```
 Input Voltage: 100-240V AC, 50-60Hz, 0.5A
 Output Voltage: 9V DC, 1.5A
```

I am interested in taking a [9V battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002BZEJQ8) and a [snap adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AXIEDX8) so I can use my device away from my outlet. However I am not sure how to ensure the output will be 9V DC and 1.5A (specifically the 1.5A).

How can I take a 9V battery plus a snap adapter and create a power supply that would be equivalent to the DC power adapter? Do I need to add a 6 Ohm resistor in the loop to ensure that I = V/R or is that too simple?

Comment: why would you think of using a series resistor with a 9 V battery? ... are you using a series resistor with the 9 V power adapter?

Comment: The gadget you want to power requires (9V * 1.5A) = 13.5W of power. This is a not a trivial amount of power for regular household batteries - even if you manage to arrange something, the batteries will run dry very quickly, necessitating frequent changes. Are you sure the thing you're powering really needs that much power?

Comment: For that kind of power, you're going to want to use six D cells in series rather than a PP3.

Comment: Perhaps you can use Lipo 16450 rechargeable batteries. They are stronger. You can have 16450 x 3 = 3.7 x 3 = 11.1V, then use LM2596 regulator to step down to 9V or 5V. This show how I am doing it: https://i.imgur.com/1mzwrYJ.jpg. Cheers.

Comment: A Li-ion battery without proper protection is a bomb waiting to explode, bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9 volt batteries are designed for low current long life applications. Even if you could draw 1.5 Amps at 9V in an ideal setup, with a typical 500 mAh 9V alkaline battery, you would get less than a 3rd of an hour life on it. In reality the battery chemistry will reduce the voltage and current capacity as the current draw increases. From https://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm you can see that a 1 Amp draw for a good battery may only give 90 mAh of capacity and the voltage drops below 7V real quick. That means you will get 7 minutes of battery life. Expensive.

Ideally what you need is modern technology. Aka a nice lithium battery pack with 9V output. You can find these offthe shelf with a usb Power delivery enabled power bank with a USB PD or Quick charge trigger module to get 9V out. These will have safety measures in them and should easily give a few hours at what you need.

Alternatively hack your device. Some devices will have internal regulators or components because they run at a lower voltage, and you may be able to bypass them.

Comment: Is this a good example of the Lithium based 9V? http://amzn.com/B07VGPK2RD or http://amzn.com/B07Z9CYCJQ

Comment: Why buy No-Name-Brand Chinese batteries from an online department store? They are not 9V (8.4V when fully charged dropping to 6V). Can you believe their mAh number? They cannot even spell Polymer, the battery is labelled Ploymer.

Comment: Do you have a link to those example 9V output lithium packs?

Answer (score 3):

9V/6 ohms= 1.5A which will kill the very cheap low power batteries extremely quickly. Why kill the battery with a parallel resistor? Rayovac does not show performance graphs so I show one of an Energizer cheap old 9V Zinv battery like what you asked about.

[image: Cheap 9V battery]

Comment: Super heavy duty are crappy zinc batteries. At least show a alkaline battery graph.

Answer (score 1):

Power adapter are rated by their maximum current and voltage, a 9V, 1.5A rating means it will output 9V max and 1.5A max. The exact current that will be output depends on the circuit.

You can think of it like this: the adapter outputs a specific voltage and then the circuit draws whatever current it wants till the adapters reaches its maximum. Kinda like with water faucet in a bathroom, water pressure will offer to push water, and you controlling the faucet will determine the amount of water flowing.

Voltage is the "Pressure pushing on electrons to move", while Current is the rate at which they move, note the quotes as this is a simplified view.

Back to you case, a common 9V battery, will not be able to output 1.5A, they are usually rated for 0.25A max, with high quality ones rated to 0.3A. You can either select a different type of battery or add 6 of them in parallel.

Adding batteries in parallel increases the max current and capacity while keeping the voltage the same.

Comment: 0.5A is a lot for regular alkaline 9Vs... they typically have several ohms of internal resistance so even if 0.5A is possible, it won't be delivered at 9V.

Comment: You are correct, i am assuming for the sake of simplicity that they use the best available batteries and that the load can tolerate lower voltage, will update the answer.

Comment: Thje batteries the OP linked to are Zinc Chloride, and are marked "Ideal for low drain devices", so probably won't be happy if asked to deliver more than 100 mA, if that.